# #VALUE Error in Data Validation Function in Excel Macro

Tags: vba, function

I have this function. But I have #VALUE error.How to solve this?

```
Function UYGULAMAADI(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Target).Select
With Selection.Validation
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, _
Formula1:="=IF(OFFSET(" & Target & ";0;1;1;1)='stackoverflow';INDIRECT('x1');INDIRECT('x2'))"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
End With

End Function
```

Comment: A function called from the worksheet (i.e., `=UYGULAMAADI(A1)` when you put this in a cell to call the function)can't operate on worksheet objects like this. Specifically, the `.Select` method is probably what's causing the function to abort early. I would expect the `.Validation` method will also error.

Comment: Thank you @David. What do you suggest for solution?

Comment: That depends on the problem. What are you trying to do?  I explain why this doesn't work as a function. It should most likely work as a sub as long as you provide a way to pass a range argument (inputbox, or use `Selection` as the input, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

A function called from the worksheet (i.e., =UYGULAMAADI(A1) when you put this in a cell to call the function)can't operate on worksheet objects like this. Almost all range and worksheet methods are forbidden inside a UDF called this way, to prevent circular reference errors, dependency errors, infinite loops, etc.

You are using the `Target` as an *input* -- that is, you want to add validation to the *target* cell.  You could do the same with `Selection`, in a subroutine

```
Sub UYGULAMAADI()

'Applies this macro to the range currently SELECTED by the user

With Selection.Validation
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, _
Formula1:="=IF(OFFSET(" & Selection.Value & ";0;1;1;1)='stackoverflow';INDIRECT('x1');INDIRECT('x2'))"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
End With

End Sub
```

Or, prompt the user for input:

```
Sub UYGULAMAADI()

'Prompts the user for an input/range
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a cell", Type:=8)

If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

With rng.Validation
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, _
Formula1:="=IF(OFFSET(" & Selection.Value & ";0;1;1;1)='stackoverflow';INDIRECT('x1');INDIRECT('x2'))"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
End With

End Sub
```